# Why observables in for loop work differently?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am learning Angular 6 now and now facing an observable issue that I can't understand.

Please take a look at my code below.

```
export class ShoppingCartComponent implements OnInit {
  cart$;
  products = {};
  constructor(private shoppingCartService : ShoppingCartService, 
  public productService : ProductService) { 
  var subscription = from(this.shoppingCartService.getCart());
  subscription.subscribe(cart => cart.subscribe(shoppingcart => {
     var items = shoppingcart.items;
     console.log(shoppingcart.items);
     for(let key in items){
         console.log(key);
         this.productService.get(key).valueChanges().subscribe(product=>{
            this.products[key] = product['title'];
            console.log(product);
            console.log(this.products);
            //console.log(key);
         });
     }
  }));
 }
}
```

cart in subscribe is Observable< ShoppingCart>.

```
export class ShoppingCart {
    constructor(public items: ShoppingCartItem[]){ }

    get productIds(){
      return Object.keys(this.items);
    }

    get totalItemsCount(){
      let count = 0;
      for (let productId in this.items)
        count += this.items[productId].quantity;
      return count;
    }
}

export interface ShoppingCartItem{
    product : Product;
    quantity : number;
}
```

This angular app gets shoppingcart from firebase database and if I run this I get weird result. Please look at the screenshots. Products object seems to be overwritten by the last key which is cauliflower.
[image]

But if I toggle back the comment which is **"console.log(key)".** It works fine like below screenshot.

[image]

Is this because of let variable in for loop?

If let keyword is replaced with var, products object only has cauliflower regardless of console.log(key).

Please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: let keyword is used to prevent problems like this one (including async cases like setTimeout or Observable.subscribe). Can you build a minimal example on StackBlitz that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Have you tried the const keyword?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var value of ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(value), 0);
}
// baz
// baz
// baz

console.log(value);
// baz
```

As a setTimeout was called outside of for-of loop it used the same `value` each time, `value` exist outside of loop (block scope).

`let` and `const` [block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2) variable.

With let keyword babel will transpile in:

```
var _arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

var _loop = function _loop() {
      var value = _arr[_i];
      setTimeout(function () {
            return console.log(value);
      }, 0);
};

for (var _i = 0; _i < _arr.length; _i++) {
      _loop();
}
```

On each iteration of for-of loop new `value` is created in `_loop` [function's scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).